# Azure Monitor vs Network Watcher

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

Can someone help me understand the difference between the Azure Monitor service and Network Watcher?
Both services monitor, diagnose view metrics and enable or disable logs for Azure resources.
The only difference I see is the offerings of the Network watcher are limited to the Virtual Network Resources only. However, the question is, can't the Azure Monitor service be used for those resources also?

Answer (score 4):

The Azure Monitor is a service that provides log aggregation and metric based monitoring of all Azure service, VNet included.

It can be used to monitor basic network metrics and integrate it in a global platform monitoring solution.

However Azure Monitor cannot perform "active diagnosis" (such as packet capture or ad-hoc network topology discovery). Those use cases are covered by the Network Watcher that can tap on the vnet/vnic level.